# How to retrieve image's name to store in image table after uploading on AWS S3 using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-8

I am uploading images on AWS S3 using laravel8 and package (league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3) with following code.

```
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $data['image_name'] = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $data['path'] = Storage::disk('s3')->put('images', $request->image);
    $data['ab'] = Storage::disk('s3')->url($data['path']);
    return $data;
```

After successful upload, Above code is returing

```
{
 "image_name": "1644919540.jpg",
 "path": "images/SYrPZTqDQgSuIvqBZzdrSX5JEmRQhwEC3muYDvJO.jpg",
 "ab": "https://abc-user-images.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/images/SYrPZTqDQgSuIvqBZzdrSX5JEmRQhwEC3muYDvJO.jpg"
}
```

I need to retrieve only the image's name in the path variable like

```
"path":"SYrPZTqDQgSuIvqBZzdrSX5JEmRQhwEC3muYDvJO.jpg"
```

Comment: It looks like you're already getting the value in JSON. Why can't you just parse it and store it in a variable? Question need more clarity

Comment: `$image->getClientOriginalName();` it will gives the files original name

Comment: @ApurvBhavsar I don't want the original name, I just want name changed after upload.

Comment: @HussainMansoor Yes. But is there any readymade solution to get the exact image name after upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use ltrim(string,charlist)

```
$image = $request->file('image');
$data['image_name'] = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$data['path'] = Storage::disk('s3')->put('images', $request->image);
$data['ab'] = Storage::disk('s3')->url($data['path']);
$image = ltrim($data['path'],"images/");
return $image;
```

The $image have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

$image_data['image_n'] = Str::of($data['path'])->substr(7);    is also working.

this is returning the exact image name.

```
{
 "image_name":"SYrPZTqDQgSuIvqBZzdrSX5JEmRQhwEC3muYDvJO.jpg"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).